# nxwebplayer fails under nxserver4 linux

Tags: nomachine-nx

At start of a nxwebplayer session (nxserver4, under debian), the connection to display:0 
fails (X server):

```
nxagentShadowInit: ERROR! Cannot shadow the display. PseudoColor
visual class is not supported. Only TrueColor visuals are supported.
```

I modified /etc/X11/xorg.conf, without result:

```
Section "Screen"
SubSection "Display"
Depth 24
Visual TrueColor
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Thanks for ideas and remarks